# Подскажите как можно сделать такую фигуру css для li

Tags: html, css

Требуется сделать такую фигуру указанием CSS свойств для списков `<li>`:

[image]

При данном коде не показываются линии вертикальные зеленого цвета.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код

```css
.list {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}


/* .list::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #363636 10%, green 10% 90%, #363636 90%);
} */

.list__item {
  position: relative;
}

.list__item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: #363636;
}

.list__item+.list__item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -11px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="uk-width-auto@m">
  <h4 style="color:#fff;">О компании</h4>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list__item">
      <a href="{{route('about_company')}}" class="uk-link-text" style="color:#fff;">О
      компании</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list__item">
      <a href="{{route('cooperation')}}" class="uk-link-text" style="color:#fff;">Сотрудничество</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list__item">
      <a href="{{route('contacts')}}" class="uk-link-text" style="color:#fff;">Контакты</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вообще то на so есть возможность вставлять изображения но всё равно вопрос в виде картинки без кода запрещён правилами ресурса ...

Comment: У меня кода нет. Я вот и спрашиваю как это можно сделать. Может кто может пример кода дать?

Comment: на div или на li на чём угодно, html5 возможности даёт большие хоть на canvas

Answer (score 4):

Использование `<ul>` и псевдоэлементов:

```css
.nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav > li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 14px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav > li::before,
.nav > li::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav > li::before {
  width: 9px; height: 9px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  left: 0; top: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav > li::after {
  width: 1px; height: calc(100% - 9px); /* высотка кружка */
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px; top: 13px;
}

.nav > li:last-child::after {
  display: none;
}

.nav > li:not(:last-child) {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>Камеры</li>
  <li>Видеорегистраторы</li>
  <li>СКУД</li>
  <li>Комплекты</li>
  <li>Тест для текста, который может вылезти на вторую строчку, ну или даже на третью, в общем проверяем "адаптивность", все дела..</li>
  <li>А у последнего полосы не будет</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: неплохо, но не `pixel perfect`, четная ширина плохо вяжется с линией толщиной в 1 пиксель (плюс заочно поставил)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, специально для вас поправил)

Comment: сразу глаз радуется, а до этого - не радовался =)

Answer (score 2):

Так надо?

```css
.body {background-color:#444; width:200px; padding:10px;}
.greenLine { color:#eee; font-family:sans-serif;}

/* necessary */ 
.greenLine {list-style-type:none;}

.greenLine li {
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
  word-break: break-word; 
}

.greenLine li:before {
      content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 11px;
    min-width: 11px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -6px;
    top: calc(1em - 2px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #444;
    z-index:1;
}

.greenLine li:after {
  content:"";
  display:block; 
  position: absolute;
  border-left:1px solid green;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  left: -1px;
}

.greenLine li:first-of-type:after {
  top:1em;
}



.greenLine li:last-of-type:after {
  bottom:calc(100% - 1em);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
<ul class="greenLine">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.cir {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.line {
  width: 0;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="cir"></li>
    <li class="line"></li>
    <li class="cir"></li>
    <li class="line"></li>
    <li class="cir"></li>
    <li class="line"></li>
    <li class="cir"></li>
    <li class="line"></li>
    <li class="cir"></li>
    <li class="line"></li>
    <li class="cir"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="menu">Menu-1</li>
    <li class="menu">Menu-2</li>
    <li class="menu">Menu-3</li>
    <li class="menu">Menu-4</li>
    <li class="menu">Menu-5</li>
    <li class="menu">Menu-6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!Это то что нужно!

Comment: @Роман, всегда пожалуйста...

Comment: @Air Очень избыточный вариант, создавать столько лишней разметки и при банальном изменении размера текста, все поплывет.

Comment: @kost1k, на `css` только так... Аккуратно подобрать размеры и ничего не поплывет.... Если знаешь лучше вариант реализации такого на `css`, покажи, буду признателен...  ***`Век живи, век учись...`***

Comment: @Air А как же псевдоэлементы? Делать маркеры для списка разметкой, это уж совсем не дело) А если у тебя динамическое количество и при адаптиве что-то происходит, все сразу сломается и ни какие подобранные размеры не помогут) Вот пример адекватной реализации https://jsfiddle.net/c95rzp1t/

Comment: @Роман, измени вопрос, нажми кнопку `править` и добавь верстку...

Comment: Вот моя верстка сейчас с использованием Uikit <div class="uk-width-auto@m">
   <h4 style="color:#fff;">О компании</h4>
   <div class="list">
    <div class="list__item">
     <a href="{{route('about_company')}}" class="uk-link-text" style="color:#fff;">О
      компании</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list__item"><a href="{{route('cooperation')}}" class="uk-link-text" style="color:#fff;">Сотрудничество</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list__item"><a href="{{route('contacts')}}" class="uk-link-text" style="color:#fff;">Контакты</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

div {display: block;}

Comment: Не имею малейшего представления что такое `Uikit`....

Comment: @Роман Если при меньшем количестве элементов линия выходит за границы, то можно использовать такой вариант https://jsfiddle.net/c95rzp1t/1/. Но в таком случае, регулировать отступы между элементами списка можно либо высотой самих элементов, либо padding'ом, но тогда положении точки придется сместить на высоту этого padding'a.

Comment: Не могу понять почему если элементов меньше четырех, то выезжает таким образом http://joxi.ru/nAyOx3XtgMdkQm

Comment: @Роман фон линии задается градиентом в процентах, изменяя высоту блока меняется и фон, я уже скинул выше еще один вариант, где такого не будет происходить

Comment: @Air простите что надоедаю, но у меня при новом варианте получается так
http://joxi.ru/D2PlYRBiqzZYY2 без линий

Comment: @Роман Отредактируй пожалуйста основной вопрос и вставь туда пример кода. Смотри внимательнее, видимо какие-то стили упустил.

Comment: Я исправил вопрос!

Comment: @Роман Только ты вставь полностью свой код, где есть проблема, а так ты мой скопировал, там все нормально отображается)

Comment: Я вот и не понимаю почему у меня не работает. Я использую вот этот css файл https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.6/css/uikit.min.css  может в нем есть какой-то стандартный стиль который бьет верстку? Замечу что это я пример файла скинул css